# Is it possible to use a value from within a 'for' loop outside of the actual loop cycle?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I have a `for` loop that cycles through my array and prints to the console each value that meets a certain condition. I would like to take these values and insert them into variables outside the loop. Is this possible?

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].catType === 'I') {           
        console.log(myArray[i].location);            
    }
    ...
}
```

I'd like to insert whatever is outputted from the `for` loop in a tooltip object that sits outside of this `for` loop.

```
var header = "<thead>" +
                 "<tr>" +
                     "<td class='legend-color-guide'><div style='background-color: " + series.color + ";'></div></td>" +
                     "<td class='key'><strong>" + <INSERT HERE> + "</strong></td>" +
                 "</tr>" +
             "</thead>";
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You can directly insert value by manipulating DOM. `document.getElementById('your_id').innerHTML = value;`

Comment: @Rohit you don't want to edit the dom from inside a for loop

Comment: I think what @Rohit was suggesting WILL work...it's just REALLY bad practice.  EDIT: on second thought, it actually won't because the value would be overwritten on each iteration of the loop...

Comment: My bad guys. Sorry :(

Comment: a (slightly) better way would be to create a variable (before the loop) to store all of the generated html, and concatenate it upon each iteration through the loop, and modify the DOM one time after the looping is completely done.

Comment: Please give more info, do you want to create TDs for every value that meets the condition inside your loop? or do you want to print all the values that meets the condition in one TD? If you want to create TDs for every value, declare a variable of type array before the loop and push to that array use `Array.push()` and inside the header variable loop over the newly created array put the `<td> value[i] </td> inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array, add the new value each time the condition is meet.

```
var arr = [];// initialize array

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].catType === 'I') {
        console.log(myArray[i].location);

        arr.push("Add Whatever Here");// append new value to the array
    }
}
```

Comment: Or use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @zero298 there are a 1,000 ways to skin a cat, this is just one way.

Comment: this is great, thanks everyone. @AdamBuchananSmith the second part is still a little grey. Now when I have my array outside of the loop, how can I dynamically print every index in the loop where I have the <insert here> text?

Comment: @KunalOjha Are you trying to output HTML or plain text as strings?

Comment: Plain text as strings

Comment: so my end goal is to have a new row <tr> for every outputted item in the loop

Comment: Oh there is an easier way to go about it, would it be ok if I did it a completely different way?

Comment: Yes, please! Im having so much trouble figuring out how to do so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115777/discussion-between-kunal-ojha-and-adam-buchanan-smith).

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but you don't (and shouldn't) want to use the output from the console. Instead, you want to append the values to a variable, and *then* set the `header` variable. Like: (I've used another example)

```
var putIn = "";
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === x) {
        putIn += array[i].property;
        console.log(array[i].property);
    }
}
var final = "on the left side " + putIn + " on the right side";
```

As you can see, I've put the values in the string and logged the elements in the array separately. There's no need to use the log values as values to insert into the string.

Comment: I imagine the OP still wants to output to the console, also he gave you the html string he wants `putIn` inserted into.

Comment: for the output you have in var final, I  want to print EACH individal item from the putIn array, I think with your output will just give the entire array in that string all in one go,

Comment: @Kunal Ojha Right, I'll update my answer. Inside the if statement, you can simply `console.log(array[i].property)` to print to the console.

Answer (score -1):

Define a global variable. Then set that variable in your loop cycle. Or create an array and push each value from your loop into the array, then you can access them from something else.